# Rediricting url dynamically from dynamically populated links

Tags: php, mysql, http-redirect, redirect

a mysql database has following three columns:

```
id  url_href              url
1    yahoo         http://www.yahoo.com
2    google        http://www.google.com
3    bing          http://www.bing.com
```

i use the following query to get the value

```
mysql_select_db($database_XYZ, $XYZ);
$query_urlencoder = "SELECT id, url_href, url FROM sites WHERE id >0 ORDER BY id DESC";
$urlencoder = mysql_query($query_urlencoder, $XYZ) or die(mysql_error());
$row_urlencoder = mysql_fetch_assoc($urlencoder);
$totalRows_urlencoder = mysql_num_rows($urlencoder);
```

the href tag

```
<a href="redirect.php?encodeurl=<?php echo $row_urlencoder['url']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row_urlencoder['url_href']; ?></a>
```

populate links on page dynamically based on repeat region like,

```
yahoo
google
bing
```

and clicking above links take the users respectively to

```
http://www.examplecom/redirect.php?encodeurl=http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.example.com/redirect.php?encodeurl=http://www.google.com
http://www.example.com/redirect.php?encodeurl=http://www.bing.com
```

but those actually aren't redirected to the respective url like

```
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.bing.com
```

how can i redirect the href links to the the above url in this case? any suggestion or reference shall be thankfully appreciated.

Comment: Is your redirect.php is correct and pointing to desired urls correctly

Comment: yes it is, otherwise i wouldn't be able to open the url `http://www.site.com/redirect.php?encodeurl=http://www.yahoo.com`. would the url be opened if redirect.php was incorrect? i'm curious to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use urlencode php function

```
redirect.php?encodeurl=<?php echo urlencode($row_urlencoder['url']); ?>
```

Comment: should the database field be named exactly `url` to utilize this php function?

Comment: there are no relations with your db field name with php function name.

Comment: i used the function like `redirect.php?encodeurl=<?php echo htmlspecialchars (urlencode($row_urlencoder['url'])); ?>` it returns `http://www.site.com/redirect.php?encodeurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com` on click but doesn't redirect the link to the expected url `http://www.yahoo.com` thanks,

Comment: Try this simple code in your redirect page
$toPage = $_GET("encodeurl");
header("location:".$toPage);
return;

Comment: @Sudip Pal, this code is almost same as suggested by `Basic Bridge` except the predefined variable and it serves the same purpose. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($urlencoder)){
echo '<a href="http://yoursite.com/redirect.php?encodeurl='.$row_urlencoder['url'].'" target="_blank">'.$row_urlencoder['url_href'].'</a>';
} ?>
```

In your redirect.php

```
<?php 

sleep(20);

header('Location:'.$_GET['encodeurl'].'');

?>
```

Comment: hey dude @ Basic Bridge, `header('Location:'.$_GET['encodeurl'].''); ?>` in redirect.php did the job. i haven't had to change anything in my existing code i posted in my question. thanks a lot. thanks too @ Dipesh Parmar.

Answer (score 0):

`rawurlencode( )` will help you.

The characters that need to be escape-encoded are the control, space, and reserved characters:

`; / ? : @ & = + $ ,`

Delimiter characters must also be encoded:

```
< > # % "
```

The following characters can cause problems with gateways and network agents, and should also be encoded:

```
{} | \ ^ [ ] `
```

PHP provides the `rawurlencode( )` function to protect them. For example, `rawurlencode( )` can build the `href` attribute of an embedded link:

```
echo '<a href="search.php?q=' .
      rawurlencode("100% + more") .
      '">';
```

The result is an `<a>` element with an embedded URL correctly encoded:

```
<a href="search.php?q=100%25%20%2B%20more">
```

PHP also provides the `urlencode( )` function that differs from the `rawurlencode( )` function in that the former encodes spaces as a + sign whereas the latter `encodes` spaces as `%20`. The use of the + character to encode a space was an early HTTP way to encode spaces.